# Calculating the partial derivative with respect to a matrix

Tags: partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

Say, $y = W^T b$ where, $ W^T \in R^{2 \times 2} $ and $ b \in R^{2 \times 1} $. Now, we want to calculate: $\frac{\partial y}{\partial W}$.

First, if we look at the dimensions: $y \in R^{2 \times 1}$. So, we know that $\frac{\partial y}{\partial W} \in 2 \times 2 \times 2$ - so it will be a third order tensor?

Second, is the following correct: $\frac{\partial y}{\partial W} = b^T \bigotimes I_{2 \times 2}$?

Are there any good resources to read up on when it comes to matrix derivatives? especially, understanding the dimensions, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my calculations,

$$\begin{matrix}\frac{dy_1}{dW_{11}}=b_1&\frac{dy_1}{dW_{12}}=b_2&\frac{dy_1}{dW_{21}}=0&\frac{dy_1}{dW_{22}}=0\\
\frac{dy_2}{dW_{11}}=0&\frac{dy_2}{dW_{12}}=0&\frac{dy_1}{dW_{21}}=b_1&\frac{dy_2}{dW_{22}}=b_2\end{matrix}$$

So it looks like $b^T\bigotimes I_{2\times 2}$ would give you $$\begin{pmatrix}b_1&b_2\end{pmatrix}\bigotimes\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\\
=\begin{pmatrix}b_1\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}&b_2\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\end{pmatrix}\\
=\begin{pmatrix}b_1&0&b_2&0\\0&b_1&0&b_2\end{pmatrix}$$

which matches

$$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{dy_1}{dW_{11}}&\frac{dy_1}{dW_{21}}&\frac{dy_1}{dW_{12}}&\frac{dy_1}{dW_{22}}\\
\frac{dy_2}{dW_{11}}&\frac{dy_2}{dW_{21}}&\frac{dy_2}{dW_{12}}&\frac{dy_2}{dW_{22}}\end{pmatrix}$$

if you write it a certain way.

Comment: Thanks, @Stacker. Just trying to understand - how did you arrive at those set of partials? I am trying to calculate this from first-principles.

Comment: I wrote W as a matrix W11,W12,W21,W22, multiplied it with b, which I wrote as b1,b2, and then I called the resulting vector y, which was split to y1 and y2. Then I took the derivative of y1 and y2 wrt each part of W.

Comment: Got it, thank you!